# How to view MongoDB indexes data structure?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

In the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) it is stated that

> Indexes are special data structures [1] that store a small portion of
>   the collection’s data set in an easy to traverse form.

How can I see these data structures? Is it possible?

I was going through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work) and I saw that in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1130/9953550) they gave an example of a schema for an index. Is there such a thing in MongoDB that is what I am trying to see. I am trying to understand indexes in MongoDB better.

Comment: Click on `[1]` link and you will the answer

Comment: The link in mongo docs? All I get from it is the name that is found in the index what other fields are there? Does MongoDB create a hash to identify the document’s location? Like it is done in sql?

Comment: [1] MongoDB indexes use a B-tree data structure.

Comment: What do you mean by "see"? Inspect the memory of a running process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an index in Mongo (using [createIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)) you specify which fields the index will use, or what you call the index "schema".

As mentioned in the docs these indexes are built as `b-trees` (don't read too much into this as indexes are a "black box" for us users), viewing the exact tree structure is not possible, but you can use [indexStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/) to get some more information on an index you created.